# How to create a tree-hierarchical structure with unique behavior for every type combination?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Assume:

1. There is some module whose interface is `IA`.
2. There is some module `B`, that takes in a parameter an instance of `IA`, and whose behavior depends upon the type of that `IA`,

meaning (pseudo code, no specific language, [even though I use Python])

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        if(type(this.ia)==A1){
             print("A1");
        }
        if(type(this.ia)==A2){
             print("A2");
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I could add some public method `foo` to `ia`, and thus the code would simplify to

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        this.ia.foo();
    }
}
```

**My question is twofold:**

1. What is the correct design to achieve this if I (for some reason) can't change `IA`, meaning, I can't add `foo()`?
2. What is the correct (scalable) design if I am allowed to change `IA` but the same problem now repeats for `A1`, `A2`, and so on, meaning

the final desired behavior is

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        if(type(this.ia)==A1){
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z1){
                 print("A1Z1");
                 print("unique treatment");
             }
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z2){
                 print("A1Z2");
                 print("special treatment");
             }
        }
        if(type(this.ia)==A2){
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z1){
                 print("Z1A2");
                 print("one of a kind treatment");
             }
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z2){
                 print("Z2A2");
                 print("Wow treatment");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and can repeat more times.

**Please notice Z1 and Z1 are the same for A1 and A2!**. And again, the same can go on, `IZ` can contain `IX` of several types, with unique behaviors

I wonder if case 2 is at all separate of modular, in the sense that, the behavior is unique for every type-combination, and no behavior can really be extracted to a more abstract level.

I still don't like the type checking, and wonder if there is something that can be done which looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the Visitor pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This does assume that you can change `IA` and friends to implement the `accept` methods

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Tagged Union Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).  Consider also [Do union types actually exist in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854282/do-union-types-actually-exist-in-python)

Some examples might be Kotlin's [Sealed Classes and When Statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).  Or Scala's [Case Classes and Sealed Traits](https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/structuring_information).

If you're using Java, it's going to be a little wordy to set up using [Paguro](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/Paguro).

```
interface Wheeled { }

class Beetle implements Wheeled { }

class Truck implements Wheeled { }

// Makes a union class.
static class Beetle_Truck extends OneOf2<Beetle,Truck> {
    private Beetle_Truck(Object o, int n) {
        super(o, Beetle.class, Truck.class, n);
    }

    static Beetle_Truck ofBeetle(Beetle b) {
        return new Beetle_Truck(b, 0);
    }
    static Beetle_Truck ofTruck(Truck t) {
        return new Beetle_Truck(t, 1);
    }
}

// Here's where we use it.
@Test public void testBeetleTruck() {
    Beetle_Truck bt1 = Beetle_Truck.ofBeetle(new Beetle());
    Beetle_Truck bt2 = Beetle_Truck.ofTruck(new Truck());

    assertEquals("b", bt1.match(beetle -> "b",
                                truck -> "t"));

    assertEquals("t", bt2.match(beetle -> "b",
                                truck -> "t"));
}
```

Note that Beetle and Truck do not need to implement a common interface at all.  For your second question, you could just do a OneOf4 similar to OneOf2.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I am using Python mostly. I was looking for an answer that doesn't rely on a specific language, but rather on OOP principles.

About the solution using union classes - It seems to me this just moves the same problem to another place. Why is this scalable? Meaning - What if I now add another `A3` and another `Z3`? Worse - What if now the tree is 5 levels deep? I would then have `Beetle_Truck_Player_Glass_Notebook extends OneOf32`. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to do something different depending on the type of the object.  And you don't want to do `if (myObj is TypeA) then ... else if (myObj is TypeB) then...`  The point of the match statement is that it's ensured at compile time to cover all the possible types.  Python doesn't have this built in, but some other languages do.  I think "Tagged Union Types" is your answer though.